# Natural sorting(Text with Numbers) for String in Apex

Tags: apex, string, sort

I must `sort strings` like "Text x.x.x(Text x)", "Text x.x.x", etc.(where x - `number`) in right way in Apex.

Something like that:

Input - ['Test 1.2(V 1000)', 'Test 1.10(V 1001)', 'Test 1.2(V 1001)', 'Test 1.2']

**Need Output - ['Test 1.2', 'Test 1.2(V 1000)', 'Test 1.2(V 1001)',  'Test 1.10(V 1001)']**

Result of `List.sort` - ['Test 1.10(V 1001)', 'Test 1.2', 'Test 1.2(V 1000)', 'Test 1.2(V 1001)')

Comment: Try with `list.sort()`;

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 `list.sort()` give another result, please see again

Comment: You can use a regular expression to convert the string into its component parts (and types i.e, use Integer for the numbers) that you then hold as attributes of a class and then implement Comparable on the class using those values. Probably several hours of work if you are not familiar with this sort of code and if you include writing a test case that verifies the sorting.

Comment: @I.Kliavakin How did you achieve the solution for this problem. I need to sort the alphanumeric versions. (1.8.44, 11.7.alpha, 9.x, Other,  Assigned)

Answer (score 2):

+1 @itzmukeshy7

You can use `sort()` method of `List` to sort the elements of the `List`. I executed it in the Developer Console successfully.

```
List<String> lstStr = new List<String>{'Test 1.1.2(V 1000)', 'Test 1.1.1(V 1001)', 'Test 1.1.2(V 1001)', 'Test 1.1.2'};
lstStr.sort();
System.debug('Sorted List::'+   lstStr);
```

Comment: I am sorry, I gave bad example, please see again what I need.